# Machform sending data to another website

Tags: php, html, json, text, machform

Has anyone accomplished using the feature on Machforms sending form data to another website? 
I have searched on the Machforms forums and have not found a solution and it seems this feature only works sending data to applications, not to files.

I'm trying to send form data to a file. Either a txt, php, html, json with no luck. It seems this feature only works with applications.

Anyone have any tips on how to accomplish sending the data to a file would be very helpful? Thanks in advance.